# nginx proxy_pass for jupyter notebook under domain.com/nb

Tags: nginx, jupyter-notebook

I'm want to use `nginx` to redirect an address to the local port `jupyter` is running on. If I do `location / {}` it works fine, but if I try `location /nb {}` or `location ^~/nb {}`and try to access through domain.com/nb `jupyter` complains that the webpage I'm trying to view doesn't exist. How can I proxy from a subpage to jupyter so that it work?

Here's the entire config:

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name domain.com;

    location ^~/nb {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your current configuration attempts to access `http://localhost:8888/nb;`. If you want to remove the `/nb` part of the URI, you will need to rewrite it, using either a `rewrite...break` or the `proxy_pass` statement itself.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite based on this I tried fixing the rewrite, but it turned out the notebook server itself does rewrites, so in the end I had to edit the notebook server config and add c.NotebookApp.base_url = '/nb/'